# Tkinter Mac application does not work properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, py2app

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, BOTTOM
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'somescript.py',])

def a():
    print("kmads")

root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x400")
root.title('Button')
Label(text='I am a button').pack(pady=15)
Button(text='Button',command=a).pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

I run this script with terminal It works fine.
But when I convert this script file to mac.app by using py2app, subprocess line doesn't (somescript.py file is not opened) work but the tkinter window is clearly there

Is there any suggestion?